Retrieve readable false field permissions in permission set
Related question: sfdx is removing metadata from permission sets when changing read/write to false
We are tracking the permssion set in reporitoy. That permission have those fields also which do not have read access also.
Now I add some new field permissions in the permisson set in my dev sandbox.
I am trying to retrieve the permission set with below package.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WorkflowFieldUpdate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WorkflowRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WorkflowRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>My_Permission_Set</members>
        <name>PermissionSet</name>
    </types>
    <version>58.0</version>
</Package>

And using sfdx command like below:
sfdx force:source:retrieve -x package.xml

But now I do not see fields with readable false in the retrieved permission set meta xml.
When I try to diff this file with the one in repository it shows thousand of changes.
To solve this I have to manually add field permisison in the repository permission set xml for the new fields.
Is there any way I can retrieve permissionset with the field which do not have any access in the permisison set so the diff with repository will show only my new fields in diff.
